# Correct way to put an <aside> element in the middle of a paragraph?

Tags: css, html, semantics

I have been reading about the semantic uses of the `<aside>` HTML5 element and it seems like a good way to handle footnotes/sidenotes since these are tangential to the main flow of text. However, this is a block-level element, so I cannot put an `aside` element inside larger paragraphs, e.g.:

```
<p>
    A b c. 
    <aside>X y z.</aside>
    D e f.
</p>
```

This breaks the paragraph into two with the `aside` content in the middle. My goal, after styling, is to see a continuous flow of text, "A b c. D e f." (with the `aside` content repositioned), or "A b c. X y z. D e f." (with the `aside` content not breaking the flow of the text).

Is `aside` the Right Thing for this job, semantically and stylistically?

Comment: Questions asking for the Right Thing are generally opinion-based, and the same applies to questions about HTML “semantics”. It should be sufficient that by HTML5 (where the `aside` element is proposed), an `aside` element is not *even syntactically* allowed within a paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<aside>` is intended to hold a section of a page that can stand alone. It's not appropriate for a footnote/sidenote within a paragraph

Comment: Mind providing some documentation to back this up?  It is not a tremendously useful answer otherwise, particularly as this point is debatable (see the recommended use of `aside` for long annotations [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#footnotes))

Comment: As I understand it, `aside` can be used both for "footnote" sort of addendums relevant to sections of the main content (rather than a linked footnote relevant to a particular sentence/fact/assertion) - e.g. information that supplements the main content - in addition to "stand alone" content like a typical generic site-wide sidebar.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside. "The HTML <aside> Element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around it, which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars or as inserts. They often contain side explanations, like a glossary definition; more loosely related stuff, like advertisements; the biography of the author; or in web-applications, profile information or related blog links."

Comment: From the page you linked: "They often contain side explanations, like a glossary definition" - this could easily apply in this case (or it could not, depending on the content).  I think the problem here is the question is not specific enough to make a real semantic decision about the markup.  My point is that sidenotes ARE (or can be) a valid use of `aside` unlike you imply, it just depends on the case.

Comment: E.g. using `aside` for a "footnote" would not be appropriate since it refers to and requires a specific line of text in the main content as context to be understood, while a "sidenote" that provides more general contextual information that can be understood independently of the main content (but is still intended to supplement it) would be an appropriate use of `aside`.  His question could refer to either case, so it seems important to draw that distinction in your answer rather than just say "no".

Comment: browsers default `<aside>` to `display: block`. Enough said. (But you can do whatever you wish.)

Comment: I'm not saying it should be nested inside a `p` like in his example (obviously not) - but he was specifically asking for semantic clarification and from a semantic standpoint you aren't really fully answering his question.  There is also arguably a very important semantic difference between using `aside` within an `article` versus outside (the latter being the more general "stand alone" content case you point to, e.g. a typical sidebar).